# ¿Como controlar las rutas con una sesión activa? - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

Un Saludo,

En algunos casos al momento de llamar una vista por el metodo get paso un parametro en la url como por ejemplo: `localhost/empresas/2`enviado el id al final de url, pero puede ser que el usuario A tenga las empresas (por ponerle un nombre a la vista) 1, 2 o 3 y el usuario B tenga las empresas 4, 5, 6. Puede surgir el caso que el usuario A cambiando el ID en la URL quiera acceder a las empresas 4, 5, 6.

La manera en como actualmente lo estoy controlando es de la siguiente forma, a través del controlador de la vista.

```html
<?php
//web.php

Route::get('/empresas/{empresa}', 'EmpresaController@exampleView')
->where('empresa', '[0-9]+')
->middleware('auth);
//Con middleware controlo que sin un inicio de sesion esta pantalla no pueda servista por ningun usuario
```

```html
<?php

public function exampleView(Empresa $empresa)
{
    if ($empresa->user_id == auth()->user()-id) {
    
      //do somthing
      return view('folder.file');
    }else{
      return redirect('/home');
    }
}
```

Creo una condición y si la relación de la tabla user en la tabla Empresas es igual al id de de la sesión activa muestre el contenido de la vista, de lo contrario me redirija al home. **Pero me pregunto ¿si laravel tiene una forma menos rudimentaria de controlar los accesos a las vistas?** a través del método get, mostrando la información solicitada al usuario correcto.

Comment: Parece un caso para implementar [Autorizaciones de acceso a los recursos](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization)

Answer (score 1):

Una forma en que se me ocurre que lo puedes hacer sin embargo es con la misma consulta es meter un middleware que quede de intermediario entre tus vistas, supongamos que tienes un middleware `empresas` y lo vas a hacer algo asi

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
namespace App\Empresa;

class empresas
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $empresa = Empresa::find($request->get("empresa"));
        if ($empresa->user_id != auth()->user()-id) {
            return redirect('home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Si te das cuenta es exactamente la misma idea, la unica diferencia es que ahora la usas en tu middleware.

Y para llamarlo solo haces

```
Route::get('/empresas/{empresa}', 'EmpresaController@exampleView')
->where('empresa', '[0-9]+')
->middleware('auth','empresa');
```

Obviamente despues de haber declarado tu middleware en `kernel.php` en

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
            ..... 
            'empresa' => \App\Http\Middleware\Empresa::class,]
```